# Why is modulus of common ratio taken for convergence of geometric series?

Tags: linear-algebra

S=a(1-r^n)/1-r, my question is why do we take |r|<1 for convergence geometric series, can r be negative and still converge or absolute value is needed to converge?

Comment: This an elementary math problem. Migrate to math?

Comment: I cant ask question on math for 7 days so i am asking here,Can you please help?

Comment: This is **not** a reason to use the wrong forum! Your question is not about physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you are given $ a + a*r + a*r^{2} + ... + a*r^{n}$ you can always say

that   $  S =   a + a*r + a*r^{2} + ... + a*r^{n} $

and then  $ r * S =   a*r + a*r^{2} + ... + a*r^{n} + a*r^{n + 1} $

So     $   S * (r - 1) =   a*r^{n + 1}   -  a  $

So      $  S =  ( a*r^{n + 1}   -  a ) / ( r -1  )  $

which only converges as n tends to infinity if $  |  r |  <  1 $

Comment: Why mod of r and not just r,i mean it will still converge or do we have to make r positive first by using mod?